# GIS blender add on error: No imaging library avilable, how to solve it?

Tags: add-on

I would like to use a blender add on called [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS). When I try to use it, I get the error message *No imaging library available, ImageIO module was not correctly installed.* I tried the solution proposed [here](https://laptopanalyst.com/blender-master-gis-addon-issues-fixed-solutions/) but it is not working for me.

~S. Pouria Doris(PCG)

Comment: That's a third-party addon but there are quite a few links for that error if you search Google. There seem to be detailed instructions [here](https://laptopanalyst.com/blender-master-gis-addon-issues-fixed-solutions/).

Comment: i've already seen this site and i didn't get that at all, if u know the soulation, i'd be great if u explain it with pics or a tutorial

Comment: The solution to your problem is [here](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: As I said, the addon is not part of Blender so we can't help you directly, but the link @Marty Fouts has given you points directly to the explanation and solution in the FAQ section of the Wiki for the addon.

Comment: thx i myself saw that but i'm kinda busy rn so i need to try that later, but thx to u guys, thank u so much, i hope that link will help meh ;)